# write to excel all non-zero-row dataframes in global environment

Tags: r, global-variables, r-xlsx

I have a set of empty (0-row) and non-empty (>0-row) **Tibbles** in my global environment and I want to **select only** the **relevant** ones, i.e. the non-empty ones and send them to a **write.xlsx** command.

It seems like it should be fairly doable task, yet I struggle to get around it.

let's say some complex code back in the process produces tibbles A,B and C, for simplicity

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
A<-tibble(a=1:3,aa=2:4,aaa=3:5)
B<-tibble(b=rep(1,3),bb=rep(2,3),bbb=rep(3,3))
B<-B %>% filter(b>4)
C<-tibble(c=3:1,bb=4:2,bbb=5:3)
A;B;C

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a    aa   aaa
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     3
2     2     3     4
3     3     4     5
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: b <dbl>, bb <dbl>, bbb <dbl>
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      c    bb   bbb
  <int> <int> <int>
1     3     4     5
2     2     3     4
3     1     2     3
```

now I want to write to excel only Tibbles A and C, for B is empty

So I tried something like

```
writexlsx<-function(x){
        if("tbl" %in% class(x)){
                if(nrow(x)>0) { 
                        write.xlsx(x,filename=paste(x,".xlsx",sep=""))
                }
        }
}

lapply(writexlsx,ls())
```

but ls() is only a list of names, not actual objects

```
ls()
[1] "A"         "B"         "C"         "writexlsx"
```

Any ideas?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get()` to get the object with a character vector:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(writexl)
A<-tibble(a=1:3,aa=2:4,aaa=3:5)
B<-tibble(b=rep(1,3),bb=rep(2,3),bbb=rep(3,3))
B<-B %>% filter(b>4)
C<-tibble(c=3:1,bb=4:2,bbb=5:3)

get("A")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a    aa   aaa
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2     3
#> 2     2     3     4
#> 3     3     4     5

writexlsx<-function(x){
  df <- get(x)
  if("tbl" %in% class(df)){
    if(nrow(df)>0) { 
      writexl::write_xlsx(df,path=paste(x,".xlsx",sep=""))
    }
  }
}

lapply(ls(), writexlsx) 
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A.xlsx"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "C.xlsx"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that gets and writes as XLSX files all dataframes in the `.GlobalRnv` or writes the dataframes passed as names in argument `dfnames`.

```
writexlsx <- function(dfnames){
  if(missing(dfnames)){
    lst <- mget(ls())
  }else{
    lst <- mget(dfnames)
  }
  lst <- lst[sapply(lst, inherits, "data.frame")]
  lst <- lst[sapply(lst, nrow) > 0]
  lapply(names(lst), function(x){
    write.xlsx(lst[[x]], file = paste0(x, ".xlsx"))
  })
}

writexlsx()
```